# Video Merging Issue using ffmpeg in C#

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to merge more then 2 videos but I am facing an issue during the video merging. The scenario is that I am creating a video from images and then merge that video with mobile recorded video. Video merging is working but the sound of the mobile video is not working. the command of video merging is as follow.

```
" -f concat -safe 0 -i " + Path + " -c copy " + output
```

Path  is the txt file in which the file path is written.
The command to make video from images is as follow.

```
" -y -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -r 1/3 -i " + filepath + " -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p " + output;
```

filepath  is the folder path where the images are as follow img000.png, img001.png and so on.

I am adding a sound file in video that I am creating from images. The command to add sound is as follow.

```
" -i inputFile -i audioiFile -c:a copy -codec:a Aac -b:a 192 k -strict experimental -shortest output"
```

Comment: This might work better at Super User, there’s a lot of ffmpeg questions and since this isn’t really related to C# it seems.

Comment: Yes, I know there are a lot of question. I have study a lot of question but did not found the exact solution. My code is working for other video that I download from Internet but it is not working properly for Android mobile recorded video.

Comment: I found the solution to merge the video. The steps are as follow:

**1.Convert the video in ts using the following command.
-i "input.mp4" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "input.ts"**

convert all files in ts which you want to merge.

2. Merge the .ts files using the following command.

**-i "concat:input.ts|input2.ts|input3.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "output.mp4"**

These steps will merge the video and also retain the audio sync